# jquery accordion link menu

Tags: jquery, html-lists, accordion, styling

Just wondering the best method to make a Jquery Accordion link menu. due to CMS restrictions, this is made more complicated for me. What I am ideally after:
A JQ menu that will parse a menu structure like:

```
<ul class="amenu">
<li><a href="">Intro to page...</a> /*This should link to the intro page, and also expand the accordion. It must be a li.*/
 <ul>
  <li><a href="">More information about parent item, styled differently and in an accordion</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Further info to above item..</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="">Another page intro</a></li>
///more sub items
</ul>
```

The issue I am facing is that the CMS I am using is quite restrictive, and I cannot add a seperate class to first and second level li's (could I achieve this in CSS, not great at lists styling!?). I would also like the accordion to open at the class level (if a sub accordion page is accessed) the CMS assigns say for argument sake Current Item which I think should be possible via the JQuery Accordion?

Jquery 1.4.3 in use but could be flexible if required.

Comment: I forgot to add, the accordion I am trying to implement is this one: http://demos.net.tutsplus.com/020_jQueryUI/accordion-custom-jquery.php. Using the JQueryUI Accordion function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these selectors :

```
   .amenu li ul { /* Second level menu */ }
   .amenu li ul li { /* Li seconde level */ }
```

To open your sub level menus :

```
   .amenu li ul { display: none; }
   .amenu li:hover > ul { display: block; }
```

If I have understood your question.

Comment: Hi Thanks for that Vincent, I stupidly forgot to point out, I am trying to use an implementation of Jquery UI Accordion, following this guide: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/exactly-how-to-create-a-custom-jquery-accordion/